# MySQL Query Into Array for preg_replace

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, replace

**ORIGINAL CODE**

```html
$sentance="are you hungry too?";
function newLanguage($text) {
 $sql = "SELECT in,out FROM words";
 $res = mysql_query($sql) or die();
 $in_array = array();
 $out_array = array();
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ 
  $in_array[] = $row['in']; // table in, NEW words
  $out_array[] = $row['out']; //table out, ENG words
 }
 return preg_replace($in_array,$out_array,$text);
}
$newwords = newLanguage($sentance);
echo $newwords;
```

**AMENDED CODE:**

```html
ini_set("display_errors", "1"); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function newLanguage($text) {

$sql = "SELECT in,out FROM words";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die();
$in_array = array();
$out_array = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ 
 $in_array[] = '/\b' . preg_quote($row['in']) . '\b/'; // table in, NEW words
 $out_array[] = $row['out']; //table out, ENG words
}

/* VERSION 2 - STATIC, FOR DEBUGGING
$in_array = array('~\you~s','~\to~s','~\too~s');
$out_array = array('noa','nie','niee');*/

return preg_replace($in_array,$out_array,$text);
}
$sentance="are you hungry too?";
$newwords = newLanguage($sentance);

var_dump($in_array);
echo $sentance;
```

**CURRENT CODE**

```html
ini_set("display_errors", "1"); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$sentance="are you hungry too?";
function newLanguage($text) {

$sql = "SELECT * FROM words";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die();  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ 
    $in_array[] = '/\b' . preg_quote($row['in']) . '\b/'; // table in, NEW words
    $out_array[] = $row['out']; //table out, ENG words
}
return preg_replace($in_array,$out_array,$text);
}
$newwords = newLanguage($sentance);
var_dump($in_array);
echo $newwords;
```

I'm having Problems with my code, for the life of me I cannot get it to work, I have worked with preg_replace before in using a word filter. Though creating a dynamic array using query results totally throws me off. I have looked at a few tutorials but none have really helped me understand where I am going wrong.

Any help would be grateful :)

**GOAL:**
Creating a New Language translation. Database holds a row with 'in' & 'out' which is both the new language and local language.

**PROBLEM:**
I'm unsure if my Arrays are being successfully populated since my preg_replace isn't working.

----**UPDATE**----

Here is what my database looks like;

```html
id          in          out
1           you         noa
2           to          nie
3           too         niee
```

- They are stored as VARCHARS

Comment: Are your `in` values really regular expressions, or just plain strings?

Comment: Can you post sample values from the `words` table? Make sure you have `error_reporting(E_ALL)` enabled? You're probably getting errors from `preg_replace`, because the regexp doesn't have proper delimiters on it.

Comment: How do I Enable error_reporting? I haven't encountered this before. Do I simply insert;

ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

above my query?

Comment: Yes, that's how you do it.

Comment: Okay, that's in. Still nothing new to report though as I'm not getting any errors though I think I have found what IS the problem though I'm unsure of how to fix it.

When I removed $newwords = newLanguage($sentance); I was able to get sentance to echo. Though with $newwords = newLanguage($sentance); in the code it wont even echo sentance.. something isn't right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ 
    $in_array[] = '/\b' . preg_quote($row['in']) . '\b/'; // table in, NEW words
    $out_array[] = $row['out']; //table out, ENG words
}
```

This turns the `in` worods into regular expressions, adding `\b` to match word boundaries.

My whole test code is:

```
<?php
$sentance="are you hungry too?";
function newLanguage($text) {
    $in_array = array();
    $out_array = array();
    $rows = array(array('in' => 'you', 'out' => 'noa'),
                  array('in' => 'to', 'out' => 'nie'),
                  array('in' => 'too', 'out' => 'niee'));
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $in_array[] = '/\b' . preg_quote($row['in']) . '\b/'; // table in, NEW words
        $out_array[] = $row['out']; //table out, ENG words
    }
    return preg_replace($in_array,$out_array,$text);
}
$newwords = newLanguage($sentance);
echo $newwords;
```

The `$rows` array replaces the database query, but the rest is essentially the same.

Comment: Updated, still not working. I'm feeling very stupid right now :( and demotivated. Sorry for wasting your time and I appreciate you taking the time to help.

Comment: Please add `var_dump($in_array)` to your question.

Comment: Are you going to add me the output of the `var_dump`? That's what I wanted to see.

Comment: How do I see the output of var_dump? I cannot see it in the console using chrome, how do I see? I dont see Errors nor is the var_dump echoing any output. This surely means that my query is not working or the array is not being built?

Comment: Okay I have something now..! :) I am seeing this outputed
**Notice: Undefined variable: in_array in /usr/shared/web/hawkw1/Hawkwoods/words/index.php on line 31
NULL are noa hungry niee?** GETTING CLOSE! :D

Comment: Becaue you removed the initializations of the arrays before the loop. Add back `$in_array = array(); $out_array = array()`.

Comment: Maybe my server isn't refreshing my changes quick enough as I did make those changes but I wasn't getting any results. Now it seems to have refreshed?

Comment: This is getting very tiresome, it seems like you're just cutting and pasting with no idea what anything means.

Comment: The last edit was 3 minutes ago. It doesn't have the array initializations. The code should still work, it just produces warnings.

Comment: The last edit was when you changed `select in, out` to `select *`. You still haven't added the output of `var_dump($in_array)` like I requested.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67542/discussion-on-answer-by-barmar-mysql-query-into-array-for-preg-replace).

Comment: @bluefeet The OP doesn't have enough rep to chat.

Comment: @Barmar Since I moved the comments to chat, they should be able to use it.

Answer (score 0):

**BIG** thank you to Barmar for his dedicated help and patience in helping me solve my question!
I have made his answer correct since he helped me so much but if you wish to use my final code that is commented please feel free.

My Goal was to IMPORT database rows and insert them into an Array which will be used with preg_replace.

**My Final Code was:**

```html
//this is the base text that will be modified using database information
$sentance="are you hungry too?";

function newLanguage($text) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM words";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(); 
    $in_array = array();
    $out_array = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        // inserts the column row 'in' into an array called in_array
        $in_array[] = '/\b' . preg_quote($row['in']) . '\b/';
        // inserts the column row 'out' into an array called out_array
        $out_array[] = $row['out']; 
 }
    //replaced any matching words from 'sentance' with 'in_array' and replaces with 'out_array'
    return preg_replace($in_array,$out_array,$text);
}

//this makes a new variable and used a function to replace the text with matches in the variable
$newwords = newLanguage($sentance); 
echo $newwords;
```

Comment: You're still missing the initializations of the arrays.

Comment: It works and I have No errors. I add the initializations and I have errors. Thank you for your help though :) I really appreciate it!

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. You got the notice about an uninitialized variable before because you were missing the initialization.

Comment: I added it due to the answer above due to the fact you mentioned it should be in there but I don't have it in my code and it works :) **P.S Thank you for being so patient, helping people isn't easy, its time consuming and frustrating but you really made me happy :) so thank you!**

Comment: The initializations should be BEFORE THE LOOP, not INSIDE it. You're totally clueless.

Comment: Barmar... Chill bro, I Have been frustated and made silly errors because I cannot think clearly. Happens to everyone. I am happy that my code works now. Chill bro. You helped someone out and I appreciate it. I am not clueless.. just clumsy and brash.